# Sim command without command window output

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'm using the `sim` command in a Matlab script to run a Simulink model. This simulink model display some stuff in the command window. What is the option for the `sim` command to remove any display that would go in the command window? So is there something similar to this that exist :

```
sim('model', 'CommandWindowDisplayVisible', 'off');
```

**Update:**

From what I found, there appears to be no such thing possible with the `sim` command. Here what I did as an alternative :

```
s = sprintf('sim(''%s'')', ModelName);
try
  evalc(s);
catch err
  msgString = getReport(err, 'extended');
  disp(msgString)
end
```

Comment: What kind of 'stuff' gets displayed in the command window?

Comment: @am304 Results and some informations about the simulation steps.

Comment: Is this the same sort of information that gets displayed when you run the Simulink model interactively rather than through the `sim` command?

Comment: @am304 Yes the same information.

Comment: Then, I'm not sure how you can turn it off using the `sim` command, since it's also there when running the model interactively. If you can find a setting in the model configuration parameters to not display that information when running interactively, that would be the way, rather than through the `sim` command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try using `evalc` to capture the output to a variable.  This way it is not displayed in the command window.

for example

```
sim('model')
```

produces output, whereas:

```
myCommandWindowOutput = evalc('sim(''model'')');
```

doesn't.

In fact, you don't even need to assign the output, you could just write:

```
evalc('sim(''model'')');
```

http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/evalc.html

Comment: That's exactly what I did. So there are no other ways with the `sim` command alone?

Comment: Not that I am aware of I'm afraid, but that's not to say they don't exist